# How to get multiple values through session from a file which is running multiple times in PHP

Tags: php, loops, session

I have a file which is **run 2 to 3 times** and there is a variable `$student_name`, and I want that variable to be available in another file. How to achieve it?

file 1.

```
$info[] = $student_name;
$_SESSION["student_name"] = $info;
```

file 2.

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($_SESSION['student_name']) ; $i++) {
   echo $_SESSION['student_name'][$i];
}
```

but I am getting only the last assigned value.

Comment: `$_SESSION['student_name'][$i];` doesn't actually do anything. Did you copy the code wrong - should there be an echo?

Comment: @ADyson thank you for response. yes there is a echo I forgot to add, I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `file 1` is executed 3 times, then `$info` will be re-created empty in that file each time - it does not persist between different script executions. So then `$_SESSION["student_name"]` will be overwritten with this new `$info` variable each time, which presumably only contains one entry.

But Session variables *are* persisted between executions, that's the whole point of them! So instead, just check whether the session variable exists, and if it does, append `$studentname` directly to that existing array. If it doesn't, create the array with the first name entry in it.

Something like this (in file 1):

```
if (isset($_SESSION["student_names"])) $_SESSION["student_name"][] = $student_name;
else $_SESSION["student_names"] = array($student_name);
```

(Note that I renamed the session key to `student_names` (plural) to be more meaningful, and reflect the fact it can contain multiple values.)